# Updating the min/max templateOptions

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Please have a look at the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pemakapadu/1/edit?js,output)

At first, `numberTest` requires the user to input a number between 5 and 10 (as noted by the description beneath it).  If you press the `change min/max` button, the min/max fields are updated to 500 and 510.  Again, you can see the description has updated to these new values.

However, it still requires the user to enter a value between the original min/max settings (5 and 10).  How do I get the validation to see the new settings?  Clearly, I am setting them correctly because the description under the field is updating correctly.  It seems that the validation is stuck with the original values.

EDIT: I added better validation messages to the field.  You can see that even the validation message thinks that the new min/max values are correct but the field still requires 5-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `expressionProperties` to change the values, but changing them manually. angular-formly does a lot of optimizations to make sure we're not adding watchers that are unnecessary. `expressionProperties` is how you inform angular-formly that these values can change.

Here you go: http://jsbin.com/xenuqo/edit?js,output

For more on `expressionProperties` see [this](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/learn-angular-formly#section--expression-properties-https-egghead-io-lessons-angularjs-angular-formly-expressionproperties-pl-7-)